# Is it possible to load images from a js file dynamically in a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a html file with some images in it. But now I want to load the images from my JavaScript file (code is shown below) into my html file div class without typing it always into my div class. Is there any way to achieve this with JavaScript, JSON or what ever?

```
var swiperExhibitors = ['141726', '141747', '141786', '144994', '145002', '145070', '145072', '151550', '168999', '233192', '545600'];

var swiperImages = ['1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg', '1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg', '1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg', '1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg', '1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg', '1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg', '1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg', 'fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg', '1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg', '1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg', '1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg'];
```

I want to write a script that do all the work for me and creates the images dynamically in my html file

Comment: You can loop through the array, creating a new image object for each item and then setting the source with the value from the array. The image can then be appended to the div. Look at `document.createElement` and `<element>.appendChild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simply looping over the `swiperImages`

```js
var swiperExhibitors = ['141726', '141747', '141786', '144994', '145002', '145070', '145072', '151550', '168999', '233192', '545600'];

var swiperImages = ['1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg', '1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg', '1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg', '1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg', '1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg', '1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg', '1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg', 'fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg', '1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg', '1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg', '1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg'];

swiperImages.forEach((name, i) => {
  var id = swiperExhibitors[i];
  var div = document.createElement("div")
  div.className = "swiper-slide";
  document.querySelector(".swipper-wrapper").appendChild(div)
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "egcf-link://dbf?id=" + id;
  div.appendChild(a);
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = name
  a.appendChild(img)
})
```

```html
<div class="swipper-wrapper"></div>
```

You can also see at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mknf3d45/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate it.. but where do I call my javascript function? My div class is empty now and it should add the images in my specific div class to trigger my slider.. div class is called div class="swipper-wrapper"

Comment: just change the selector `"body"` inside the querySelctor, for your div

Comment: Is it possible to make it inserts the images with the id and image name like this: <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="egcf-link://dbf?id=141726"><img src="../img/swiper/1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg"/></a></div>

Comment: What i mean is to insert the swiper Exhibitors ID´s as well like shown above: should look like this in the end: <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="egcf-link://dbf?id=141726"><img src="../img/swiper/1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg"/></a></div>

Comment: let me create a fiddle for you

Comment: I've added a fiddle link in my answer ans also updated the snippet in the answer

Comment: try it and let me know

Answer (score 3):

This will do you can create images dynamically-[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_create)

```js
var swiperImages = ['1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg', '1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg', '1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg', '1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg', '1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg', '1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg', '1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg', 'fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg', '1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg', '1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg', '1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg'];

function myFunction(src) {
  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", src);
  x.setAttribute("width", "304");
  x.setAttribute("height", "228");
  x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}


swiperImages.forEach(el => {
 myFunction(el)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it.

`var i;
for (i = 0; i < swiperImages.length; ++i) {
    // do something with swiperImages[i] like appending image
}`

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic loading of images in html you can try :

```
<html>
<div id="test">
</div>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<swiperExhibitors.length;i++){
        var ele = document.createElement("img");
        ele.setAttribute("src",swiperExhibitors[i]);
        test.appendChild(ele);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery, you could do it like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="swiper-slide"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
var image = [{imgId: '141726', img: '1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '141747', img:'1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '141786', img: '1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '144994', img: '1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145002', img: '1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145070', img: '1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145072', img: '1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '151550', img: 'fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '168999', img: '1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '233192', img: '1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '545600', img: '1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg'}]

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(image, function( key, obj ) {
        $( ".swiper-slide" ).append( `<a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=${obj.imgId}"><img src="../img/swiper/${obj.img}"/></a>`);

    });
});
</script>
```

this will only work if your JQuery file is in the root of your folder and if all your images are in the root

this is the result

```
<html><head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=141726"><img src="../img/swiper/1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=141747"><img src="../img/swiper/1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=141786"><img src="../img/swiper/1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=144994"><img src="../img/swiper/1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=145002"><img src="../img/swiper/1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=145070"><img src="../img/swiper/1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=145072"><img src="../img/swiper/1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=151550"><img src="../img/swiper/fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=168999"><img src="../img/swiper/1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=233192"><img src="../img/swiper/1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg"></a>
        <a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=545600"><img src="../img/swiper/1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg"></a>
    </div>


<script>
var image = [{imgId: '141726', img: '1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '141747', img:'1432890452.7057_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '141786', img: '1538377347.3443_114_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '144994', img: '1495453007.7039_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145002', img: '1433941431.3552_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145070', img: '1491818250.7553_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '145072', img: '1364303014.8606_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '151550', img: 'fa71eb9a8367a0ec85c7b6c05a05b6ef_01_07_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '168999', img: '1474012701.9219_3_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '233192', img: '1546596386.5453_145_o.jpg'}
          ,{imgId: '545600', img: '1554193616.0853_145_o.jpg'}]

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(image, function( key, obj ) {
        console.log('obj:   ' + obj);
        console.log('obj.imgId: ' + obj.imgId);
        console.log('obj.img:   ' + obj.img);

        $( ".swiper-slide" ).append( `<a href="egcf-link://dbf?imgId=${obj.imgId}"><img src="../img/swiper/${obj.img}"/></a>`);

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I insert it like this: <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="egcf-link://dbf?id=141726"><img src="../img/swiper/1437645467.1063_3_o.jpg"/></a></div>  it should include the id and the image name like shown

Comment: I have edited my answer above to satisfy your requirements